# WPF DataContext source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I populate my controls by binding them to a class, as in this example:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/api/Customer/" + txtNumber.Text);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var customer = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Customer>();
this.DataContext = customer;
```

This works fine.

I also use the same controls as search criteria, ie. the data the user enters in any controls should be collected and sent back to the server to query the db.

Is there a simple way to collect this data or do I have to loop through the controls and do the collection myself?

This is the XAML:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:Server.DTO;assembly=Server.DTO" mc:Ignorable="d" x:Class="Client.Forms.Reference.DataForm"
    Title="Preisstufe" Height="346" Width="459" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ShowInTaskbar="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ResizeMode="NoResize" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StatusBar x:Name="statusBar" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="20">
            <StatusBarItem x:Name="statusBarItem" Content="" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </StatusBar>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightColorKey}}"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Canvas>
            <Label Content="Number:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="87,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtNumber" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="185,36,0,211" Text="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="76" KeyDown="txtNumber_KeyDown"/>

            <Label Content="Description:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="62"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtDescription" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="185,64,0,183" Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="236"/>

            <Label Content="Abbr:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="87" Canvas.Top="91"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAbbr" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="185,93,0,154" Text="{Binding Abbr, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75"/>

            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into binding the controls to properties in the codebehind. This also works with TwoWay binding and would make your task much simpler. This is achieved in WPF using DependancyProperties

Comment: Is there an example that I might follow?

Comment: Post some of your XAML and I will amend it